# How does Fubini's theorem apply here? Expectation of product of functions of independent variables.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

**Background:** Here is the version of Fubini's Theorem that was proven in my course

> Theorem 4.23 (Fubini's theorem) Consider $(E, \mathcal{E},
>  \mu)=\left(E_1 \times E_2, \mathcal{E}_1 \otimes \mathcal{E}_2, \mu_1
>  \otimes \mu_2\right)$ with $\mu_i\left(E_i\right)<\infty$. (i) If $f$
> is non-negative measurable, then $$ \int_E f \mathrm{~d}
>  \mu=\int_{E_1}\left(\int_{E_2} f\left(x_1, x_2\right)
>  \mu_2\left(\mathrm{~d} x_2\right)\right) \mu_1\left(\mathrm{~d}
>  x_1\right) . $$
>
> In particular, we have $$ \int_{E_1}\left(\int_{E_2} f\left(x_1,
>  x_2\right) \mu_2\left(\mathrm{~d} x_2\right)\right)
>  \mu_1\left(\mathrm{~d} x_1\right)=\int_{E_2}\left(\int_{E_1}
>  f\left(x_1, x_2\right) \mu_1\left(\mathrm{~d} x_1\right)\right)
>  \mu_2\left(\mathrm{~d} x_2\right) . $$ (ii) If $f$ is integrable, then
> set $$ A=\left\{x_1 \in E: \int_{E_2}\left|f\left(x_1,
>  x_2\right)\right| \mu_2\left(\mathrm{~d} x_2\right)<\infty\right\} $$
> has full measure, i.e. $$ \mu_1\left(E_1 \backslash A\right)=0 . $$

Moreover, if we set $$ f_1\left(x_1\right)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
 \int_{E_2} f\left(x_1, x_2\right) \mu_2\left(\mathrm{~d} x_2\right) &
 x_1 \in A \\ 0 & x_1 \notin A \end{array},\right. $$ then $f_1$ is a
$\mu_1$ integrable function with $$ \mu_1\left(f_1\right)=\int_E f
 \mathrm{~d} \mu $$

The following theorem was proven in my course

> Proposition 4.24 Let $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ be random variables on
> $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ with values in $\left(E_1,
>  \mathcal{E}_1\right), \cdots,\left(E_n, \mathcal{E}_n\right)$
> respectively. We define $$ E=E_1 \times \cdots \times E_n, \quad
>  \mathcal{E}=\mathcal{E}_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes \mathcal{E}_n . $$

Then $X=\left(X_1, \cdots, X_n\right)$ is $\mathcal{E}$-measurable and
the following are equivalent: (i) $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ are independent.
(ii) $\mu_X=\mu_{X_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes \mu_{X_n}$. (iii) For any
$f_1, \cdots, f_n$ bounded and measurable, we have $$
 \mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{k=1}^n f_k\left(X_k\right)\right]=\prod_{k=1}^n
 \mathbb{E}\left[f_k\left(X_k\right)\right] $$

However, I am having some difficulties with the proof. In particular with

> - (ii) $\Rightarrow$ (iii): By assumption, we can evaluate the expectation $$ \begin{aligned} \mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{k=1}^n
>    f_k\left(X_k\right)\right] & :=\int_E \prod_{k=1}^n f_k \circ X_k
>    \mathrm{~d} \mathbb{P} \\ & =\prod_{r=1}^n
>    \int_{E_r}\left(\prod_{k=1}^n f\left(x_k\right)\right)
>    \mu_k\left(\mathrm{~d} x_k\right) \\ & =\prod_{k=1}^n \int_{E_r}
>    f_k\left(x_k\right) \mathrm{d} \mu_k\left(x_k\right) \\ &
>    =\prod_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E}\left[f_k\left(X_k\right)\right] . \end{aligned} $$ (by definition) (By assumption) (by Fubini) (By
>   definition)

**Question:** How does the given version of Fubini's theorem apply here? In the hypithesis for Fubini we always had integrability or the function being non-negative. Here we have a mere bounded and measurable. Surely there is a mistake?

Comment: You are in a probability space. Every bounded and measurable function is integrable.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @DavidGao. I can no see that we can use the second version. On another note, whenever we we use the second form with integrability do we bother writing out that we subtract a measure zero or do we treat this as an equivalent function under the equivalence measure 0?

Comment: As far as I can tell, when people apply Fubini generally they don’t bother with saying there’s a set of measure zero on which $\int_{E_2} f(x_1, x_2) \mu_2(dx_2)$ may not be defined. They just treat $\int_{E_2} f(x_1, x_2) \mu_2(dx_2)$ as a function that’s defined almost everywhere since that is enough to then integrate it with respect to $\mu_1$.

Comment: Great! Feel free to post this as an answer and I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Glad to have helped! I’ve posted my first comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $f_i$ is bounded and measurable, so is $f_i \circ X_i$. Since we are in a probability space, all bounded and measurable functions are integrable, so the second form of the Fubini theorem applies.